# How to limit to max 83 Chars per single line in RichTextBox

Tags: wpf, richtextbox

Im trying to make a recreation of MSWord using WPF RichTextBox and Toolbar, so one of the recently issues is the following:

In MSWord document...

...with Font Family Times New Roman, 11, Justify a single line contains 95 Chars
...with Font Family Times New Roman, 11, Justify, Bold a single line contains 83 Chars

about margins
It will be more recommended to work with margins or limit chars per line? 
Cause when user inputs are , . or anothers ASCII wich size is shorter than others ones, the max chars in single line "Changes".
So if use margins is most propertly - how the WPF RichTextBox manage margins ?

Thanks!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Trying to limit characters per line sounds like a nightmare to me.  You're better off getting rid of the default `ControlTemplate` for `RichTextBox` so you just have the text, then setting the `Margin` on your `RichTextBox` so the text "floats" in the middle:

```
<Grid xmlns="http://schemas.microsoft.com/winfx/2006/xaml/presentation" xmlns:x="http://schemas.microsoft.com/winfx/2006/xaml">
    <ScrollViewer>
        <RichTextBox Margin="30,0">
            <RichTextBox.Template>
                <ControlTemplate TargetType="{x:Type RichTextBox}">
                    <Border x:Name="PART_ContentHost" Margin="2" Background="Transparent" BorderBrush="Transparent"/>
                </ControlTemplate>
            </RichTextBox.Template>
        </RichTextBox>
    </ScrollViewer>
</Grid>
```