# WPF: Limit number of characters in one row

Tags: c#, .net, wpf, richtextbox

I'd like to have "80 characters per line" setting for WPF RichTextBox control. Is there any nice way to do this?

Answer (score 0):

Check [this](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/639634/wpf-how-to-limit-to-max-83-chars-per-single-line-in-richtextbox). It might be what you're looking for.

Comment: Thank you, Peter!

I'm agree with Robert Macnee: "Trying to limit characters per line sounds like a nightmare to me" :).

Unfortunately, in my case margins will not help, since user can change  font settings.